# Can not re-register mesos agent

Tags: mesos

After updating properties (`isolation`) of `mesos-slave` it fails to re-register:

```
6868 status_update_manager.cpp:177] Pausing sending status updates
6877 slave.cpp:915] New master detected at master@192.168.1.1:5050
6867 status_update_manager.cpp:177] Pausing sending status updates
6877 slave.cpp:936] No credentials provided. Attempting to register without authentication
6877 slave.cpp:947] Detecting new master
6869 slave.cpp:1217] Re-registered with master master@192.168.1.1:5050
6866 status_update_manager.cpp:184] Resuming sending status updates
6869 slave.cpp:1253] Forwarding total oversubscribed resources {}
6874 slave.cpp:4141] Master marked the agent as disconnected but the agent considers itself registered! Forcing re-registration.
6874 slave.cpp:904] Re-detecting master
6874 slave.cpp:947] Detecting new master
6874 status_update_manager.cpp:177] Pausing sending status updates
6869 status_update_manager.cpp:177] Pausing sending status updates
6871 slave.cpp:915] New master detected at master@192.168.1.1:5050
6871 slave.cpp:936] No credentials provided. Attempting to register without authentication
6871 slave.cpp:947] Detecting new master
6872 slave.cpp:1217] Re-registered with master master@192.168.1.1:5050
6872 slave.cpp:1253] Forwarding total oversubscribed resources {}
6871 status_update_manager.cpp:184] Resuming sending status updates
6871 slave.cpp:4141] Master marked the agent as disconnected but the agent considers itself registered! Forcing re-registration.
```

It seems to be stuck in an infinite loop. Any idea how to start fresh slave? I've tried to remove `work_dir` and restart `mesos-slave` process but without any success.

The situation was caused by accidental rename of `work_dir`. After restarting `mesos-slave` it wasn't able to reconnect nor kill running tasks. I've tried to use `cleanup` on slaves:

```
echo 'cleanup' > /etc/mesos-slave/recover
service mesos-slave restart
# after recovery finishes
rm /etc/mesos-slave/recover
service mesos-slave restart
```

This partially helped, but there are still many zombie tasks in Marathon, as Mesos master is not able to retrieve any information about that task. When I'm looking at metrics I found out that some slaves are marked as "inactive".

**UPDATE:** in master logs appears following:

```
Cannot kill task service_mesos-kafka_kafka.e0e3e128-ef0e-11e6-af93-fead7f32c37c 
of framework ecd3a4be-d34c-46f3-b358-c4e26ac0d131-0000 (marathon) at
scheduler-e76665b1-de85-48a3-b9fd-5e736b64a9d8@192.168.1.10:52192
because the agent cac09818-0d75-46a9-acb1-4e17fdb9e328-S10 at 
slave(1)@192.168.1.1:5051 (w10.example.net) is disconnected. 
Kill will be retried if the agent re-registers
```

after restarting current `mesos-master`:

```
Cannot kill task service_mesos-kafka_kafka.e0e3e128-ef0e-11e6-af93-fead7f32c37c 
of framework ecd3a4be-d34c-46f3-b358-c4e26ac0d131-0000 (marathon)
at scheduler-9e9753be-99ae-40a6-ab2f-ad7834126c33@192.168.1.10:39972 
because it is unknown; performing reconciliation

Performing explicit task state reconciliation for 1 tasks 
of framework ecd3a4be-d34c-46f3-b358-c4e26ac0d131-0000 (marathon) 
at scheduler-9e9753be-99ae-40a6-ab2f-ad7834126c33@192.168.1.10:39972

Dropping reconciliation of task service_mesos-kafka_kafka.e0e3e128-ef0e-11e6-af93-fead7f32c37c 
for framework ecd3a4be-d34c-46f3-b358-c4e26ac0d131-0000 (marathon) 
at scheduler-9e9753be-99ae-40a6-ab2f-ad7834126c33@192.168.1.10:39972 
because there are transitional agents
```

Comment: Can you attach Master log?

Comment: I couldn't find anything relevant in the master log. It looks like mesos marked old slaves as inactive an it's still waiting for their recovery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The split-brain situation was caused by having more than one `work_dir`. In most cases it might be enough to move data from the incorrect `work_dir`:

```
 mv /tmp/mesos/slaves/* /var/lib/mesos/slaves/
```

Then force re-registration:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/mesos/meta/slaves/latest
service mesos-slave restart
```

Currently running tasks won't survive (won't be recovered). Tasks from old executors should be marked as `TASK_LOST` and scheduled for cleanup. Which will avoid problem with zombie tasks, that Mesos is unable to kill (because they were running in different `work_dir`).

If the `mesos-slave` is still registered as inactive, restart current Mesos master.

Comment: Nuking the `latest` folder worked like a charm. Thank you.